# Dart: how to "await" for Future.wait's cleanUp?

Tags: dart, async-await

Taking the following code as an example, it is possible to infer that Future.wait's cleanUp is not "awaited" when calling `await Future.wait`.

If I don't include the statement "1 - must wait here", the test will not pass.

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  test('test Future.wait', () async {
    final waitSeconds = 5;
    DateTime slowOkExecutedTime;
    DateTime slowErrorExecutedTime;
    DateTime cleanUpExecutedTime;
    DateTime slowCleanUpExecutedTime;

    Future slowOk() {
      return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: waitSeconds), () {
        slowOkExecutedTime = DateTime.now();
        return true;
      });
    }

    Future slowError() {
      return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: waitSeconds), () {
        slowErrorExecutedTime = DateTime.now();
        throw Exception("SlowError");
      });
    }

    Future slowCleanUp() {
      return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: waitSeconds), () {
        slowCleanUpExecutedTime = DateTime.now();
        return true;
      });
    }

    try {
      await Future.wait([
        Future.microtask(() => slowOk()),
        Future.microtask(() => slowError()),
      ], cleanUp: (value) async {
        cleanUpExecutedTime = DateTime.now();

        expect(value, true);
        expect(slowOkExecutedTime != null, true);
        expect(
          cleanUpExecutedTime.isAfter(slowOkExecutedTime),
          true,
        );

        return await slowCleanUp();
      });
      fail("Should have thrown SlowError");
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error.toString().contains("SlowError"), true);
    }

    expect(slowOkExecutedTime != null, true);
    expect(slowErrorExecutedTime != null, true);
    expect(cleanUpExecutedTime != null, true);
    expect(slowCleanUpExecutedTime != null, false);

    // 1 - must wait here
    await Future.delayed(
        Duration(milliseconds: waitSeconds * 1000 + 10), () {});

    expect(slowCleanUpExecutedTime != null, true);
    expect(
      cleanUpExecutedTime.isAfter(slowOkExecutedTime),
      true,
    );
    expect(
      cleanUpExecutedTime.isAfter(slowErrorExecutedTime),
      true,
    );
    expect(
      slowCleanUpExecutedTime.isAfter(cleanUpExecutedTime),
      true,
    );
    final now = DateTime.now();

    print(
        'Clean up executed time: ${slowCleanUpExecutedTime.toIso8601String()}');
    print('                   Now: ${now.toIso8601String()}');

    expect(
      now.isAfter(slowCleanUpExecutedTime),
      true,
    );
  });
}
```

I just want to wait for the cleanUp to run before Future.wait returns.

Is there a recommended way to solve this problem, maybe using another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method passed to `onCatch` will be called synchronously and expects no return value. If you need to await or return things within that method, you might want to re-evaluate if there might be another way to do what you're doing.

If you absolutely need to make the outer context wait for an asynchronous `onCatch` method, you would need to elevate the futures to the outer context so you can await on them separately.

```dart
final cleanUpFutures = <Future>[];
try {
  await Future.wait([
    Future.microtask(() => slowOk()),
    Future.microtask(() => slowError()),
  ], cleanUp: (value) {
    cleanUpFutures.push(() async {
      cleanUpExecutedTime = DateTime.now();

      expect(value, true);
      expect(slowOkExecutedTime != null, true);
      expect(
        cleanUpExecutedTime.isAfter(slowOkExecutedTime),
        true,
      );

      await slowCleanUp());
    }());
  });
  fail("Should have thrown SlowError");
} catch (error) {
  expect(error.toString().contains("SlowError"), true);
}

await Future.wait(cleanUpFutures);

...
```